# reload uitableview to bottom cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, scroll

im creating a chat app, and I display each message thru a cell in the uitableview. However, each time i reload the tableview, it displays the content from the first cell down. I want to arrange my table so that when it reloads, it is "scrolled" all the way down, thus displaying the most recent message.

I've done some research on the docs, but im very very new to programming so im not sure how to set it up. I think i need the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method, but im not sure how to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi jeff If my answer solves your problem then please accept that.

Answer (score 6):

You should insert another row at the end of the table view, when you do that you need to know the last row no.

So you can call this function to insert the new row

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

like this

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
lastRow++;
```

and then animate the table view to scroll to last row by calling this function.

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

like this

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionButtom animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 5):

Use This

```
int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-1;
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Hope this Solve Ur problem.

Comment: +1 for this line,[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
 i used it and achieved my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling the table view can easily be achieved using the `–scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` method:

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1000 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];

Of course, you need to adjust the values for the indexPath.

Answer (score 0):

[self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.messages count]-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];